# Parametric equation to place a leaflet marker on the circumference of a circle is not precise?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, leaflet, mapbox

I am working on an application where I have the center of a circle and the radius and I am plotting the circle with the help of Leaflet.

I placed a marker on the north most end of the circumference and made it draggable.

```
var circle = L.circle(coords, radius).addTo(map);

convertRadiusToLatitude = parseInt(response.radius)/111111;

var coordsOnRadius = [parseFloat(response.lat) + convertRadiusToLatitude, parseFloat(response.long)];
var markerOnRadius = L.marker(coordsOnRadius, {draggable: true}).addTo(map);
```

Now, this adds the marker to the circumference and now I wanted it to be draggable only on the circumference itself for which I used the parametric equation.

**Parametric equation**

```
x = Xc + R * cos(theta)
y = Yc + R * sin(theta)
```

**Code for dragging**

```
markerOnRadius.on('drag', function(e){

    bearing = marker.getLatLng().bearingTo(markerOnRadius.getLatLng());

    var markerOnRadiusX = parseFloat(response.lat)  + ((0.000009 * parseFloat(response.radius)) * Math.cos( toRad(bearing) ));
    var markerOnRadiusY = parseFloat(response.long) + ((0.000009 * parseFloat(response.radius)) * Math.sin( toRad(bearing) ));

    markerOnRadius.setLatLng([markerOnRadiusX, markerOnRadiusY]);
});
```

**The `bearingTo` method:**

```
L.LatLng.prototype.bearingTo = function(other) {
    var d2r  = L.LatLng.DEG_TO_RAD;
    var r2d  = L.LatLng.RAD_TO_DEG;
    var lat1 = this.lat * d2r;
    var lat2 = other.lat * d2r;
    var dLon = (other.lng-this.lng) * d2r;
    var y    = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    var x    = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
    var brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
    brng = parseInt( brng * r2d );
    brng = (brng + 360) % 360;
    return brng;
};
```

**Issue**

When I start dragging the marker, this code is working fine and brings it back to the circumference at the bearing at which the marker is dragged to. But there is one problem, the coords on the circumference are slightly off and in terms of longitude. When the bearing is 0 (north), the coords are perfect, but when it is 90 (east), the longitude is slightly less that it should for the marker to be at the circumference.

Again at 180 (south), coords are perfect, but at 270 (west), the longitude calculated is slightly less and the marker tends towards the radius again.

So basically if you visualize the marker being dragged, it starts perfectly on the north end and starts coming inside the circle slightly increasing with the bearing till it reacher 90 and then starts going towards the circumference again till 180 when it is perfect again.

It forms more like a ellipse if you get the gist of it.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Could anyone tell me why is longitude coming a little off and why the marker moves in an elliptical path. Has it something to do with the world coordinates and window coordinates. Or are my equations slightly off somewhere?

Comment: Is this something to do with the projection you're using? Is the circle being plotted in something different to the base map...?

Comment: It might be projection issues but me being a beginner with maps cannot fathom how to go around this problem. Any idea?

Comment: OK. Perhaps have a read here http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#iprojection to understand a little. I'm only on mobile so a comprehensive answer is a little difficult. I would say to check what projection your base map and circle is in verses what projection the new marker is in. They should all be in the same (WGS84, Web Mercator etc.)

Comment: This seems useful enough. So do you recommend that I project all the points and then after calculating the coords to the marker on the circumference, unproject them to plot them?

Comment: Overall I would say, just use one projection. As you hint at Mapbox in the question tags, use the Web Mercator, that's probably what your base map is in. Then, just make sure all your calculations etc are resulting in points/polygons that are in the Web Mercator projection. At leat then you would know of this is a solution. A great way to test outside of Leaflet would be to use QGIS, add a base map in say WGS84, then add some non WGS84 data to demonstrate the difference. If you can get when you want in a full GIS application you have a better chance of fixing your web map.

Comment: How to check which projection is my map using? And how to convert my markers to that particular projection. Other than this, half of the terms you mentioned are foreign to me. Could you link me to a guide or a blog about these things where I can learn more?

Answer (score 0):

It does look like a projection issue. In your dragging code you are basically doing

```
 lat = a + r cos(baring)
 long = b + r sin(baring)
```

giving a circle in the Lat-Long coordinates. This would work fine if you were at the equator with Mercator projection. You will get more distortion as you move further towards the polls.

Assume you are using the defaults for Leaflet [reference doc](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-usage) You have the EPSG3857 [Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator) coordinates.

If you want to ensure you have a exact circle it will be better to work using screen coordinates. You can get these using methods on the [ICRS](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icrs) objects. First get the coordinate system `L.CRS.EPSG3857` and use the `latLngToPoint` and `pointToLatLng` methods.

```
var crs = L.CRS.EPSG3857;
var zoom = ...; // how you calculate your zoom factor

markerOnRadius.on('drag', function(e){

    var markerLL = marker.getLatLng()
    var morLL    = markerOnRadius.getLatLng();
    var markerP  = crs.latLngToPoint(markerLL,zoom);
    var morP     = crs.latLngToPoint(morLL,zoom);
    // get the distance between the two points
    var dist = markerP.distanceTo(morP);
    // Get the vector from center to point
    var A = morP.subtract(markerP);
    // scale so its of the desired length
    var B = A. multiplyBy( factor / dist);
    // Add on the center
    var C = markerP.add(B);
    // Convert back to LatLong
    var D = crs.pointToLatLng(C,zoom);
    markerOnRadius.setLatLong(D);
});
```

Comment: Some of this is making sense to me but I am still confused. How do I calculate the zoom and factor?

Comment: The factor will just be the radius of the circle in pixels. I think you can get the zoom from `map.getZoom()`.

Comment: I tried this but I am afraid I cannot get this to work. I used `map.getZoom()` for the zoom and I replaced `factor/dist` by `radius/6378800` where 6378800 is the radius of the earth. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Not the radius of the earth, the radius of the circle you want to draw in pixels.

Comment: How do I convert the radius in pixels?

Comment: I think you will need to do some experiments and read the documentation yourself. Study the ICRS class and its methods, put some know positions in and look at the numbers you get out.